# No PyQt4 on anaconda for py36

Tags: pyqt4, anaconda, python-3.6

I'm trying to install PyQt4 on anaconda, I looked for the available versions of PyQt and I can see that the the PyQt4 is not available for my version of Python which is, 3.6.1

```
      conda search pyqt
      4.10.4                   py26_0  defaults
      4.10.4                   py27_0  defaults
      4.10.4                   py33_0  defaults
      4.10.4                   py34_0  defaults
      4.10.4                   py26_1  defaults
      4.10.4                   py27_1  defaults
      4.10.4                   py33_1  defaults
      4.10.4                   py34_1  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_0  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_0  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_2  defaults
      4.11.4                   py34_2  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_2  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_3  defaults
      4.11.4                   py34_3  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_3  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_4  defaults
      4.11.4                   py34_4  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_4  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_5  defaults
      4.11.4                   py34_5  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_5  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_6  defaults
      4.11.4                   py34_6  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_6  defaults
      4.11.4                   py27_7  defaults
      4.11.4                   py34_7  defaults
      4.11.4                   py35_7  defaults
```

I only find a zip file for PyQt4 on sourceforge and it says that I must install SIP, and I don't know how to do it can you help me?

Comment: The SIP installation instructions can be found [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html).

Comment: However, why do you want this combination of versions? It seems to me that you can either use an older python version (3.5), or use a newer PyQt version (5.x). This way you can just install PyQt with Anaconda, which will make it **much** easier.